# Covariance Matrix of zero mean complex vector

Tags: complex-analysis, statistics, random-variables

$$\textbf{f}=[f_1, f_2, f_3];\quad \textbf{g}=[g_1, g_2, g_3]  $$

$f_1,f_2,f_3,g_1,g_2,g_3$ are all independent identically distributed zero mean complex random variable.

**h** = elementwise wise Schur-Hadamard product of **f** and **g**.

What is the covariance matrix of **h**? Is that diagonal matrix?

Comment: $h = [f_1g_1, f_2g_2, f_3g_3]$, right?

Comment: yes. you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that, for every $i \neq j$, $(f_{i},g_{i})$ is independent of $(f_{j},g_{j})$. Hence $f_{i}g_{i}$ is independent of $f_{j}g_{j}$. Hence, the covariance matrix of $h$ is diagonal. It remains to find the variance of $f_{i}g_{i}$.

\begin{align*}
  Var[f_{i}g_{i}] &= E[(f_{i}g_{i})^{2}] - E[f_{i}g_{i}]^{2}           \\
                  &= E[f_{i}^{2}]E[g_{i}^{2}] - (E[f_{i}]E[g_{i}])^{2} \\
                  &= Var[f_{i}]Var[g_{i}]
\end{align*}

Hence,

$Var[h] =
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
Var[f_{1}]Var[g_{1}] & 0 & 0 \\
0 & Var[f_{2}]Var[g_{2}] & 0 \\
0 & 0 & Var[f_{3}]Var[g_{3}] \end{array} \right)$

Comment: If abs(**f**) and abs(**g**) are rayleigh distributed, will the covariance matrix of **h** be the same?